# how to get the selected entry from jmenu (rookie)

Tags: java, actionlistener, jmenu

I just did some attempts with JMenus. 
Now I would like to react on the selected item. But I’m not sure what’s the best way finding the selected item. 
It works as expected, if I add an actionListener to each MenuItem and get the actionCommand from the thrown actionEvent. Unfortunately that means that I need an addListenerMethod in my menu for each item. 
Now I’m wondering if there is a more elegant way. Can I add the listener directly to the menu and receive the selected item? Later on I would like to add submenus to my menu. 
Thanks for help.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starter starter = new Starter(); 
        starter.work();

    }

    private void work()
{
    Test test = new Test(); 


    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());

        }
    };

    test.addDateiListener(al);
    test.addt1Listener(al);
    test.addt2Listener(al);
    test.setVisible(true);


}

}

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;


private JMenu datei; 
private JMenuItem t1, t2;

public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 815, 394);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    datei = new JMenu("Datei");
    menuBar.add(datei);

    t1 = new JMenuItem("t1");
    datei.add(t1);

    t2 = new JMenuItem("t2");
    datei.add(t2);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


}

public void addDateiListener(ActionListener al)
{
    datei.addActionListener(al);
}

public void addt1Listener(ActionListener al)
{
    t1.addActionListener(al);
}
public void addt2Listener(ActionListener al)
{
    t2.addActionListener(al);
}


}
```

Comment: Using `(Abstract)Action`s or `ActionListener`s is the right way to use this. But you are looking for another way?

Comment: Yes I'm wondering, if I really have to add a listener to each single item. I would prefere one listener for the whole menu